# Solr SQL for Single Solr Instance

Tags: solr

I was excited to hear that Solr 6 had an SQL interface, but soon found that it only works with SolrCloud and not a single Solr instance. We currently have two Solr servers. One is a master production server and it is replicated to a slave reporting server. I would love to be able to use SQL on the slave.

So a couple questions.

Is it actually possible to use SQL on a single Solr instance and I just missed something?

If I need to use SolrCloud for SQL, how can I set that up and maintain a similar architecture to what I have now? That is, I only have two hosts, all production traffic including writes go to one host and all background reports go to the other host.

I welcome any other suggestions you might have.

Comment: SolrCloud supplants the old master slave replication according to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Replication+Screen but I have not yet gone that way.

Answer (score 0):

This blog explains how SQL is integrated, and it looks as if you cannot do it with just Solr.

https://sematext.com/blog/2016/04/18/solr-6-solrcloud-sql-support/